# не работает hover '+'

Tags: html, css

Есть такой рабочий код

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}

.ceniForHover:hover+.circleForCen,
.circleForCen:hover {
  background-color: #c9e8fa;
  border-color: #c9e8fa;
}

.circleForCen:hover+.ceniForHover,
.ceniForHover:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ceniForHover">кккккк</div>
<div class="circleForCen">dfdffdf</div>
```

При наведении на "ceniForHover" оба hover-а работает, а при наведении на "circleForCen" работает подсветка.
hover работает на конкретном диве и на тех кто после него, а на выше него нет.
как сделать это без js?
За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Да вроде никак. Можно вешать уникальный класс только на каждый див и так писать css

Comment: `+` смотрит только вперед, а в данном случае: `.circleForCen:hover + .ceniForHover` после _circleForCen_ нет элемента с классом _ceniForHover_ вот ничего и не подсвечивается

Comment: Оберните эти элементы в общий родитель - и можно развлекаться.

Comment: `ceniForHover` - normalno tak nazvali.

Comment: в сайте другой вариант, здесь написал приращенный, в один див не получится.
значит без js невозможно?

Comment: только через родителя можно сделать исключением

Comment: @Crantisz, а чего ответ не написал?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

сам отвечу на свой вопрос: НИКАК, только javascriptom

```
$('.circleForCen').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').find('.ceniForHover').addClass('active');
});
$('.circleForCen').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').find('.ceniForHover').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант можно использовать в некоторых случаях:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
.container:hover > div:not(:hover){
    background-color: #c9e8fa;
    border-color: #c9e8fa;
 }
.container > div:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
    <div class="ceniForHover">кккккк</div>
    <div class="circleForCen">dfdffdf</div>
</div>
```